# Replacing empty strings with NULL value whenever a CSV file is loaded

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am working with CSV files to load them to BigQuery tables with the help of LoadJobConfig and load_table_from_uri. I have some empty strings in the CSV and when those are loaded it gets loaded as empty strings but not as NULL values.What I want is to load the empty strings as NULL values.

I have this code written in Python:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = 'test_project'
dataset_id = 'test_dataset'
table_id = 'test_table'

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

uri = f"gs://test_bucket/test.csv”

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
    create_disposition=bigquery.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    skip_leading_rows=1, 
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField(“column1”, "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(“column2”, "STRING"),
    ],
    field_delimiter=';',
    allow_quoted_newlines=True
)

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)

table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(uri, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
load_job.result()

print(f"Loaded {load_job.output_rows} rows into {table_ref.path}")
```

I tried using null_marker in LoadJobConfig but it is not working as expected. Also I don't want to use autodetect=True for schema.
Is there anyway to replace the empty strings with null values before the CSV is loaded and then load them using the URI?
Sorry if I got something wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did not work with null marker (custom null value). by default empty string are considered as null. it's what you expect. Why are you not happy with it?

Answer (score 1):

When loading a CSV in BigQuery, if the CSV empty values are like this: *value1,value2,,,,valueX,valueY* then in BigQuery the empty values are loaded as NULL.

But, if in the CSV empty values are like this: *value1,value2,"","","",valueX,valueY* (with quotes) then BigQuery will load them as empty string, not as NULL. Probably you file has quotes for the empty values.

If you have control over how the CSV is generated, you can replace the "", to get the desired result.  Another option is to load the data as you do right now, and then run a query to replace the empty strings with NULL. But this will add another step to your ingestion, and you'll pay for the extra query.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Yckeb. Unfortunately I don't have the control over the generation of the CSV file and they gets stored the like the second way you mentioned. And yes the second option you suggested will just add another step and more cost.I thought there must be some inbuilt function in BigQuery that I am not aware of and can help me acheive my goal. Maybe I will have to look for some othe way. Anyways thanks for replying.